# Display a specific dashboard by default for a specific user role

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to configure Dynamics CRM 2011 online so that it shows a specific dashboard by default for a specific user role. Is this possible through some setting or by writing customization code using a plugin or javascript?

For example if John the CEO logs in - he should see the annual revenue dashboard, if a sales person logs in they see the leads dashboard.
The dashboards are public dashboards and not personal dashboards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the on-premise version, probably the fastest way to do this is to access the database table `UserSettingsBase` and update the `DefaultDashboardId` column to the guid of the dashboard you want each user to have. (Edit - just realized you're using CRM Online, so this is not applicable.)

You can accomplish the same in the API framework by instantiating the `UserSettings` entity for each user, finding each user's appropriate `roleid`, and updating the `DefaultDashboardID` property of the `UserSettings` entity. An example is below.

```cs
using (OrganizationServiceProxy _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri("Your CRM Server"), null, null, null))
{
    _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
    using (OrganizationServiceContext osc = new OrganizationServiceContext(_serviceProxy))
    {
        var usersSettings = from u in osc.CreateQuery<SystemUser>()
                            join ur in osc.CreateQuery<SystemUserRoles>() on u.SystemUserId.Value equals ur.SystemUserId.Value
                            join r in osc.CreateQuery<Role>() on ur.RoleId.Value equals r.RoleId.Value
                            select new
                            {
                                id = u.SystemUserId.Value
                                , roleName = r.Name
                            };

        foreach (var users in usersSettings)
        {
            UserSettings us = new UserSettings();
            us.SystemUserId = users.id;
            switch (users.roleName)
            {
                case "CEO":
                    us.DefaultDashboardId = Guid.Parse("2E3D0841-FA6D-DF11-986C-00155D2E3002"); //the appropriate dashboardid
                    break;
                //case "Sales Person"
                //case "..."
                //default: ...
            }
            _serviceProxy.Update(us);
        }
    }
}
```