# Custom Welcome Screen in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I Want to Show custom welcome screen when a user logs in to Dynamics CRM 2016. 
I searched and i just got how to disable welcome screen tour but i couldn't find how to show my own custom screen (message or HTML).


Any help is appreciated.


Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a dashboard with a single large HTML web resource.

Place your content inside that HTML web resource.

Set that dashboard as the default for new users. [Display a specific dashboard by default for a specific user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091861/display-a-specific-dashboard-by-default-for-a-specific-user-role)

Comment: Thanks James this workaround seems useful although i wanted to show a welcome screen just like Microsoft tour screen comes only once when the user is logged in.

Answer (score 4):

You can also add your welcome page as HTML web resource, add its link to your sitemap and set this sitemap subarea as a default tab for every user.

EDIT (detailed description):

1. Create custom HTML web resource and publish it in CRM.
2. Edit your sitemap to contain link to newly created web resource. Sample configuration below:

[Sample](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/342a604821bdbef738be4d201482d43d)

In my case my web resource HTML name is "new_welcome.html"

3. Go to user's personal options and set your new site.map position to be your user's default tab. You may do this with CRM interface (separately for every user :()) or with the tools for personal options mass update (for example with User Settings Utility from XrmToolBox)

Sample results of above mentioned operations:
[image]

Comment: Please add more detail, along with relevant code if possible

Comment: Detailed description added in previous post.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, yes this is just another explanation of what James said the difference is here i am adding my web resource to the site map and in that solution i am adding it into the dashboard.Actually i wanted to show just once like welcome screen of microsoft tour.

Comment: There is no out of the box mechanism providing functionality similar to CRM welcome page. I suppose you could add the popup window in the custom welcome page set in sitemap and after closing it redirect parent window to the “real” CRM start page. However, this design may be tricky. I do not have any practical experience with implementing above described solution so I do not know what obstacles may be met during implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Solution of you problem is **Announcements**.

Its easy to configure and easy to circulate the information across all the users.

Follow the below links for more information about Announcement,

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/broadcast-announcements-to-an-entire-organization.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to use announcements because of the following reasons:

1. It is legacy functionality from CRM 2011 version.
2. It does not support rich text formatting or html components, images, etc.
3. You still need to create custom web resource to present it to the end user (so from the work effort perspective it also does not make sense)